# Why is CSS copying in multiline in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm copying styles from Chrome Dev Tools and pasting it into my IDE. It is pasting in multiline.

Chrome Version:   [image]

How I copied:   [image]

This happens after pasting:    [image]

Comment: It's a bug, fixed in Chrome Canary and, soon, beta.